# preg_match matching specific characters = { } [] *

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

```
if (preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]+/', $test4, $matches))
```

This will match any non alphanumeric character. I only want a match on `{ } [ ] * =` regardless of order and any other characters between them. Can this be done?

I have tried `\=, \[, \], \{, \}, \*` but that didn't seem to help?

I have a string that may or may not contain the characters listed. I would like to use preg_match to find out if the string does contain any of those characters, regardless of order or position in string.

Comment: I don't understand what you wanna do. Please be more clear and write an example of what you want. And what output you expect.

Comment: Hi. I have a string that may or may not contain the characters listed.

I would like to use preg_match to find out if the string does contain any of those characters, regardless of order or position in string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
if (preg_match ('/[{}\[\]=*]+/', $test4, $matches))
```

If you want to find all the matches rather than just the first, you should use `preg_match_all`.

Comment: I've taken the curlys out for now..

`if (preg_match ('/[\[\]=]+/', $test4))` - this seems to work.

If I wanted to match as above but include any words within the brackets, could that be done ? ie : [list]  ?

Answer (score 0):

Those characters, with the exception of the equals sign, are control characters in regular expressions. You will have to treat them differently.

I would recommend reading the [PCRE Regex Syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

To get what you're looking for, try this.

```
preg_match('/\[(.*)\]/', $test4, $square_matches);
preg_match('/\{(.*)\}/', $test4, $curly_matches);

// or, if this is your approach (it's hard to tell from your description)
preg_match('/([\[\{=\*](.*)[\]\}=\*])/', $test4, $matches);
preg_match('/([\[\{=\*](.*?)[\]\}=\*])/', $test4, $matches); //non-greedy
```

Comment: Curly braces and `*` don't have special meaning inside brackets, they don't need to be escaped.

Comment: @Barmar: it's the same with the opening square bracket :)